# Will Microsoft Touch Mouse work?

Tags: drivers, mouse, hardware, multi-touch, microsoft

I would like to buy [Microsoft Touch Mouse](http://www.microsoft.com/hardware/en-US/p/touch-mouse) but I don't know if it's going to work. I am interested especially on the multitouch functions (gestures) and touch scrolling. Have anyone tested it on Ubuntu?

Comment: https://github.com/cemmanouilidis/naturalscrolling/issues/35

Comment: Well, try the stuff given here http://blog.maurus.be/index.php/2011/09/ms-touch-mouse-reverse-engineering/ . If it works let me know.

Comment: @AartiElly it seems there hasn't been any updates for a while, any idea if theres another option?

Comment: @Ghost did you try the given blog. I have been trying to find a solution but it seems nobody found one till now.

Comment: I've tried both of those with this mouse and they are more proofs of concept than drivers. They only visualize the input data from the mouse, but don't translate it into anything the OS can work with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just bought it today. It works like a regular mouse, scroll works but is not smooth. Gestures doesn't work at all, those need to be implemented by reverse engineering. It has only one physical button, it detects where is your finger in order to decide if is a right or left click. with both fingers on the touch surface every click is a left clock, it doesn't have a middle click.

Comment: I have this mouse too, and can confirm all of this is true. I also noticed that it sometimes takes it a few seconds to register a scroll event at all.

Comment: There is too few information about how this mouse works over any linux distribution, nobody made a review so I bought it hoping for a good result even when I knew it was going to not work as expected. Is a shame, is a great mouse and I only use Ubuntu, no windows to enjoy it. I guess it is a charm in windows 8 interface.

Comment: That's what I've heard too. I figured it'd work as a basic mouse and eventually someone would hack together full support...